# Store the IDs in the Parent Model of the Child Models which are currently related via ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three models, currently i am using an url like so to do updates and get content:

> http://localhost:8000/manuscripts-api/manuscriptlibrary/28/

My question relates to the approach i should use so that i can include in my ManuscriptItem model **the IDs of the related Libraries and Settings**. What kind of fields can i add to the ManuscriptItem model that does this?

My models:

```
class ManuscriptItem(models.Model):
    """Represents a single manuscript's content"""

    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts_api.UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=99999999, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses when it needs to convert the object to a string"""
        return str(self.id)


class ManuscriptLibrary(models.Model):
    """Represents a single manuscript's library"""

    manuscript = models.OneToOneField(ManuscriptItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookmarks = models.CharField(max_length=99999999)
    history = models.CharField(max_length=99999999)

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses when it needs to convert the object to a string"""
        return str(self.manuscript)


class ManuscriptSettings(models.Model):
    """Represents a single manuscript's settings"""

    manuscript = models.OneToOneField(ManuscriptItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    citation_suggestions = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    terminology_suggestions = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paper_suggestions = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses when it needs to convert the object to a string"""
        return str(self.manuscript)
```

My serializers:

```
class ManuscriptItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for manuscript items."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.ManuscriptItem
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'content')
        extra_kwargs = {'author': {'read_only': True}}


class ManuscriptLibrarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for a manuscript's library."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.ManuscriptLibrary
        fields = ('id', 'manuscript', 'bookmarks', 'history')


class ManuscriptSettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for a manuscript's settings."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.ManuscriptSettings
        fields = ('id', 'manuscript', 'citation_suggestions', 'terminology_suggestions', 'paper_suggestions')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to add any new fields to the ManuscriptItem model. You can access the id of the related ManuscriptLibrary and ManuscriptSettings objects by defining the related_name property of the foreign key.

```
class ManuscriptLibrary(models.Model):
    manuscript = models.OneToOneField(ManuscriptItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='library')


class ManuscriptSettings(models.Model):
    manuscript = models.OneToOneField(ManuscriptItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='setting')
```

Once this is migrated, you can use `manuscript_item.library` to access the related library object, and `manuscript_item.setting` to access the related setting. Accessing ids can be done via `manuscript_item.library.id`.

Edit: To display the ids in the serialized object, you can modify your ManuscriptItemSerializer as given below

```
class ManuscriptItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    library = ManuscriptLibrarySerializer(required=False)
    setting = ManuscriptSettingsSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.ManuscriptItem
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'content', 'library', 'setting', )
```

Comment: Hi Arjun, where do i make the necessary changes (add your manuscript_item.library.id) so that i can pass this information to the front end when i send a GET request to a single ManuscriptItem?

Comment: How are you serialising the model for the response? Can you share that code?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thank you making the changes, will leave a comment as soon as im done :)

Comment: How do i point to these:     library = ManuscriptLibrarySerializer(required=False)
    setting = ManuscriptSettingsSerializer(required=False). Its telling me "NameError: name 'ManuscriptLibrarySerializer' is not defined". i think they must not be in scope or something

Comment: define the other serializers before the ManuscriptItemSerializer as they are being referenced inside it

Answer (score 1):

by the docs [one_to_one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

your `ManuscriptItem` instance has two property `manuscriptlibrary` -- instance of the `ManuscriptLibrary` model and `manuscriptsettings` instance of the `ManuscriptSettings` model. So you can get the id by `manuscriptlibrary.pk` and `manuscriptsettings.pk`, but may be best solution for greater readability you can use `related_name` as arjun27 write.

Comment: yes, using the related_name ability is completely new to me! sorry if it takes a while to understand